# PHP - An array called from a sql database does not implode properly, but an array created directly does?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-server, pdo

I am using PDO to call my database from xampp's phpmyadmin.
XAMPP version 7.0.1-0

When I create an array from scratch, and implode it, it gives me the results I want to see.

For Example:

```
$arr = array('Hello','World!','Beautiful','Day!');
echo implode(" ",$arr);
```

Which gives me:

> Hello World! Beautiful Day!

However, when I do the same thing to my database query, this happens:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\WHS_Webtour\Search_Categories\People_Search_Result\people_search.php on line 57
>
> Array Array Array Array Array Array Array...

I have used `var_dump()` to see if the array actually shows and it does.

This is the code I used to call from my sql database:

```
    function getData($db)
    {
        $stmt = $db->query('SELECT NAME FROM people');

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

I then added `echo implode(" ",$result);` which gave me the error result above.

If this helps, I had imported a database file which was converted from a .dbf to a .sql.

**UPDATE**
I updated this line of code: `$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
It only prints out one out of 50 names.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($result);` ?

Comment: can you add a piece of var_dump result, what you received at the time execution, so that it will be brief and easy to solve.

Comment: You can't simply change the `$result` you must implement the `while` loop as well. This will continually pull all 50 names (or however many exist). I updated my answer to clarify

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`fetchAll()` returns an array of arrays (a multidimensional array). Multidimensional arrays cannot be converted to text straight away due to constraints in the language. Try to return your values with `fetch()` which will get one row as a single array. You do this in a loop:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch() {
    $line = implode(" ",$row);
}
```

[PDO Fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Since you're only getting one column from the database could put all of the returned values in an array:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch() {
    $names[] = $row['NAME'];
}

$allNames = implode(" ", $names);
```

This way you push each returned item into an array (`$names`) which you can then implode.

Comment: You didn't concate the value so in $line always get last row value

Comment: The OP was asking about *why* his `implode()` was failing, not how to get the entire array imploded @ParthChavda

Comment: Have an upvote for giving away knowledge for the 'why' of the question. ^^ EDIT: I didn't mean edit it to make my answer completely irrelevant. =P

Comment: @Jon This part helped me. Now I can put all the names into a text file to filter out other names.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to do this right in your Query.

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(`NAME` SEPARATOR ' ') AS `NAMES`,
    1 AS `x` 
FROM `people` 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY `x`
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your query, I'm guessing you are wanting to implode all the names, but the problem you are running in to is that each row you fetch is going to be an array.

```
function getData($db)
{
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT NAME FROM people');
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $names = array();

    foreach($result as $name) {
        $names[] = $name['NAME'];
    }
    return $names;
}
```

This specifically will return the information in the way you are anticipating it. It will go through each row and pull the name out in to a new array that will then be returned.

Answer (score -1):

`fetchAll()` returns an array of arrays. If you want to `implode()` your data, you may want to try something like this using `fetch()`:

```
function getData($db)
{
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT NAME FROM people');

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo implode(" ",$row);
    }
}
```

That should help!

Comment: The code you gave me was able to display all of the names I have stored in the database. Excellent! Thank you.

Comment: Oh, wait. The separator is not showing up. Why is that?

Comment: What separator are you expecting to see in the output?

Comment: @JesseSchuettinger Because this will go through and separate each `$row`, but since you are only getting one result in each `$row`, there's nothing to actually implode. Look at Jay's Answer below.

Comment: Because there is only one object in each array the separator doesn't show up. It is the same issue you would have with my first code block. Jon covers putting all of the names into a single array which can then be acted upon with an implode @JesseSchuettinger

Answer (score -1):

```
$implodedVal = implode(', ', array_map(function ($indArray) {
  return implode(", ", $indArray);
}, $result));
```

edited function

```
function getData($db) {
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT NAME FROM people');
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return implode(', ', array_map(function ($entry) {
            return implode(", ", $entry);
            }, $result));
}
```

This could help you, if I'm not wrong in understanding your question.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.